# importing pyautogui in ubuntu throwing KEYERROR :DISPLAY

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/home/prasoon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/home/prasoon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 160, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

Python version- Python 2.7.15rc1

While running "import pyautogui" this error is being thrown

I run the following commands -

```
pip install `python3-xlib`

sudo apt-get install scrot

sudo apt-get install python3-tk

sudo apt-get install python3-dev

pip install pyautogui
```

Comment: Are you using the X display server or wayland?

Comment: I am using X display

Answer (score 9):

You have to correctly set environment variable `DISPLAY`. It should be defined by your OS. If it's not, you can define it manually.

**Option 1** - run python with:

```
DISPLAY=:0 python
```

**Option 2** - set environment variable in Python

```
import os

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
```

**Option 3** - put it to you `.bashrc` file

```
echo "DISPLAY=:0" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: In addition to this I needed `pip install python-xlib`

Answer (score 1):

Debian 10. crontab RUN pyautogui script to GNOME Screen

```
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
os.environ['XAUTHORITY']='/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.position())
```

Comment: I am using this for the raspberry pi 4 but it isnt working

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue when using a combination of `tox` and `pytest` to test some code that imports `pyautogui`. Even if I use `setenv` to set `$DISPLAY`, I found I also needed to set `$HOME`. After I set `$HOME`, it still broke because I didn't have a `$HOME/.Xauthority` file.

A better solution for me was to just mock `pyautogui` since I never want the mouse to move around during unit tests anyway.

To do this, I created a fixture file at the root of my `tests` directory (`tests/conftest.py`) with the following content:

```
import sys
from unittest import mock
 
# Mock pyautogui to prevent it breaking on import
sys.modules["pyautogui"] = mock.MagicMock()
```

This works well as long as you keep in mind that `pyautogui` and all of its functions/classes are going to be mocks in all of your tests (this can be limited to particular tests if needed, see the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/fixtures.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files)). For me (and most people, I think), this is a feature, not a bug, since it means you don't have to continually mock these functions in individual tests.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you can't use `Display`. To fix this type this in your `bash` terminal:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

This should fix it. Now you can run your `pyautogui` code:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)
pyautogui.moveTo(200, 300)
#And so on...
```

Comment: This completely made my problem worse.

Comment: @Jeffplays2005 care to explain how? saying something doesn't work does not narrow it down for anyone.

Comment: I tried `import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
os.environ['XAUTHORITY']='/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
import pyautogui` but now I get an error - `Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I'm running the code in `Pyspark`

Comment: any update on that issue as I have the same

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are installing python 3 libraries but you are running python 2.7.

To use pyautogui in python 2.7, replace:

- `pip install python3-xlib` with `pip install python-xlib`
- `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` with `sudo apt-get install python-tk`

You may or may not need the dev tools, but try those changes first and let me know if that works.