# How to solve pywhatkit KeyError in pyrhon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, display, python-module

```py
import pywhatkit as pwt
number=input("Enter the number: ")
msg=input("Msg: ")
pwt.sendwhatmsg_instantly(number,msg)
```

And then I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in 
> start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
> exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  **main**.**dict**)
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywhatkit/**init**.py", line 16, in 
> from pywhatkit.whats import (
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywhatkit/whats.py", line 7, in     import pyautogui as pg
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/**init**.py", line 249, in 
> import mouseinfo
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mouseinfo/**init**.py", line 223, in 
> _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError(key) from None
> KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

[Program finished]

Comment: I think this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244164/importing-pyautogui-in-ubuntu-throwing-keyerror-display

Comment: Key (pun intended) is in the last lines: `...packages/mouseinfo/init.py", line 223, in _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])` -> it looks like environment variable DISPLAY is not defined

Comment: I tried import os os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0' os.environ['XAUTHORITY']='/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority' import pyautogui but now I get an error - Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory.