# trying to import pyautogui on wsl ubuntu throwing KEYERROR :DISPLAY

Tags: python, pyautogui, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I know this question is a clone of many similar questions but none of them had any answers except this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244164/importing-pyautogui-in-ubuntu-throwing-keyerror-display). I tried everything that where suggested in that question including putting `"DISPLAY=:0"` in my bashrc(zshrc in my case) and running python with `DISPLAY=:0 python` or using `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'` but every time result was same, it throw me even longer but same error for every 3 solutions.

update:
running `echo $DISPLAY` returns nothing and running `xhost +` on my terminal throws `zsh: command not found: xhost` (since I saw first one was asked from person with a problem same as me and second one was suggested as an temporary solution)

the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pedram/anaconda3/envs/PyBot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/pedram/anaconda3/envs/PyBot/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.socket = connect.get_socket(name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 76, in get_socket
    return mod.get_socket(dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 78, in get_socket
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Had same issue with headless Pi long ago, I solved it by adding "Dummy" HDMI which emulate display, but for WSL you might need to find way to add software dummy display (which I failed)

Comment: WSL on Windows 10 does not run Linux GUI applications -- This is really a "general computing" issue, not unique to software development.  Please see [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1580610/1210833) on Super User or [What's the easiest way to run GUI apps on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/q/993225/1165986) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you for your response. I'm not trying to build a gui app, I wanted a module to interact with websites(press buttons and fill some fields on those websites) I did some research and found this module. is there any other module which I can achieve this without encountering with these problems?

Comment: @pedi_ch The answers I pointed to aren't about *building* a GUI app, just running them -- PyAutoGUI is, by definition, a GUI app/library, which Windows 10 WSL does not support out-of-the-box -- You'll need to configure WSL as referenced in the those answers in order to run it.