E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'; hitting this error when I try to import in my unit test
My unit test's path is: poker_bot_final/test_suite/test_app.py
And inside this unit test package, right at the top I am doing an import
from app import (are_check_raise_conditions_met, go_to_the_right_street, run_this_on_pre_flop_app_dot_py,
                 fill_my_hand_rating_on_flop_turn_river, run_new_hand, analyse_current_street,
                 calculate_no_players_to_act, am_i_in_position_to_bettor_calculator, my_SPR_calculator)

But I run into:
    ImportError while importing test module '/Users/patrickchong/Desktop/poker_bot_final/test_suite/test_app.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../miniconda3/envs/plo/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_suite/test_app.py:3: in <module>
    from app import (are_check_raise_conditions_met, go_to_the_right_street, run_this_on_pre_flop_app_dot_py,
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

I should mention that I DO have an __init__.py file in all of the python directories.
The root of my project is poker_bot_final

Is that the complete error message? Do you have specific messages pointing to the location of the exception?

thanks for the comment, I've added the full trace

Ohh is the error because of my virtual env? It's strange because when I run the unit test directly in my Pycharm it works but when I run it from my terminal (from the root of the project), it throws the above error. And I am using the same virtual env in both!

where is app.py located?

It is in poker_bot_final/app.py

Then your import statement is wrong

What should the import statement be?

For reference I found what I needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244164/importing-pyautogui-in-ubuntu-throwing-keyerror-display
